# How to know which proxy is youtube site connecting?

Tags: proxy

I have so many bulk proxies with same port, but I don't know to which proxy YouTube site connects, Actually I was pasting each proxy in chrome proxy settings & seeing it connecting or not. which makes time waste.

Is there any alternative way for this?

My Aim: I have to sort out working one & delete the remaining proxies from bulky list

I know **there are more easy way to access youtube**, But I want to know which proxy is connecting youtube from a list of bulk proxies.

For example: I have 4 proxies with me, In that forth one only connecting to youtube remaining 3 showing me blank page for youtube.com.

Comment: Presumably you could write a program in the language of your choice, use the language's support for setting a proxy in its runtime, and then for each proxy in your list, set the proxy, try to connect to Youtube, check the response you get, and decide if the proxy is ok.

Comment: I am beginner, I don't know about writing a program.

Comment: I think manual check is only option, I think. :(

Comment: Maybe [superuser](https://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate place to ask this question then(maybe they have a recommendation for a tool you can use to check the list), this site is for answering specific programming related questions.